# gcc raises "unrecognized command line option" error with pkg-config

Tags: c, gcc, gtk, zsh, pkg-config

I am trying to compile a gtk program using the tutorial [here](http://blog.borovsak.si/2009/09/glade3-tutorial-2-constructing.html). When I issue the command

```
gcc -o tut tut.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0)
```

I get the following error:

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0
-I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0
-I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0
-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1
-I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz  -Wl,--export-dynamic -pthread
-lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0
-lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lfreetype
-lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0  ’
```

gcc is version 4.8.2. pkg-config is version 0.26. i have libgtk2.0-dev installed.

I can compile simple c programs fine.

How do I resolve the "unrecognized command" problem?

---

[update from comment]

I am using `zsh`.

Comment: I removed the "-pthread" from the output of 

    pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0 
and stick the ouput of that command to the end of the gcc command
and the compilation went ahead without errors.

Comment: If I give invalid options to my gcc, each unrecognized command line option is given on a separate error message. This seems to be one argument. Do you use `"$(...)"` instead of just `$(...)` or something similar?

Comment: @mafso, i just use $(...), no quotes.

Comment: But still, this seems to be one argument to gcc… Can you do the same you did when you removed the "pthread" (as described in your comment) but not remove it?

Comment: Compiles without any warnings here. What shell are you using?

Comment: @alk, i am using zsh. since you mentioned it, i tried to compile it in a bash shell, and what do you know, it compiled cleanly. thanks for the hint.

Comment: @mafso, since the compilation went smoothly in a bash shell, that the options seem to be one argument to gcc might have something to do with zsh.

Comment: Added an answer, so your questions gets a chance to get closed.

Comment: Interesting… [The Debian `zsh` man page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=zshexpn&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy) says _“If the substitution is not enclosed in double quotes, the output is broken into words using the IFS parameter.”_ under “COMMAND SUBSTITUTION”. Anyway, good you've found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a shell issue.

What shell are you using?

In case it's not `bash`, give `bash` a try.