# GCC gives undefined reference when using pkg-config to link with the XCB library

Tags: c, gcc, x11, ld, xcb

I'm following an X11 programming tutorial from [here](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/tutorial/). The page gives 2 commands that can be used to compile an XCB-based program:

```
gcc -Wall prog.c -o prog `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb`
```

and

```
gcc -Wall prog.c -lxcb
```

Now, I've tried both. The first one says `gcc: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘--cflags’`. Apparently this is a shell related problem (As I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24350919/gcc-raises-unrecognized-command-line-option-error-with-pkg-config)). So I tried `bash`. And this gives a different error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnURTF3.o: in function `useXlib':
example.c:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnURTF3.o: in function `useXlibProperly':
example.c:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `XInternAtoms'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccnURTF3.o: in function `main':
example.c:(.text+0x4b1): undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/usr/bin/ld: example.c:(.text+0x559): undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is the same as what I get with `gcc -Wall prog.c -lxcb`. So I guess `bash` fixed the problem but there are 2. And in Atom, when you hover over a function, it shows you which header it is from. But in this one I didnt't get anything.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the result of `pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk yes sorry about that

Comment: @Gerhardh I tried that before. Its says ```-lxcb```. I thought its meaning was to add a single ```-lxcb``` flag instead of the whole thing. But that doesn't work either. Its a typo btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like over the years the libraries got splitted and the function declarations were moved to a different library. And now `xcb` depends on `X11` or something like that or maybe `pkg-config --libs xcb` should output `-lX11`, no idea. Anyway, the following works:

```
gcc -Wall 1.c -lxcb -lX11
```

or the following works too:

```
gcc -Wall 1.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs xcb) $(pkg-config --cflags --libs x11)
```

Would be nice to ping the maintainer of that introduction to let him know he should update the page.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll let him know.